# How can I use GDB to get the length of an instruction?

Tags: gdb

The problem I am trying to solve is that I want to dynamically compute the length of an instruction given its address (from within GDB) and `set` that length as the value of a variable. The challenge is that I don't want any extraneous output printed to the console (e.g. disassembled instructions, etc.).

My normal approach to this is to do `x/2i ADDR`, then subtract the two addresses. I would like to achieve the same thing automatically; however, I don't want anything printed to the console. If I could disable console output then I would be able to do this by doing `x/2i ADDR`, followed by `$_ - ADDR`.

I have not found a way to disable the output of a command in GDB. If you know such a way then please tell me! However, I have discovered `interpreter-exec` and GDB/MI. A quick test shows that doing `x/2i` works on GDB/MI, and the value of `$_` computed by the MI interpreter is shared with the console interpreter. Unfortunately, this approach also spits out a lot of output.

Does anyone know a way to either calculate the length of an instruction without displaying anything, or how to disable the output of `interpreter-exec`, thus allowing me to achieve my goal? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give an arguably cleaner and more extensible solution that's not really shorter. It implements `$instn_length()` as a new GDB convenience function.

Save this to **instn-length.py**

```
import gdb

def instn_length(addr_expr):
    t = gdb.execute('x/2i ' + addr_expr, to_string=True)
    return long(gdb.parse_and_eval('$_')) - long(gdb.parse_and_eval(addr_expr))

class InstnLength(gdb.Function):
    def __init__(self):
        super(InstnLength, self).__init__('instn_length')

    def invoke(self, addr):
        return instn_length(str(long(addr)))

InstnLength()
```

Then run

```
$ gdb -q -x instn-length.py /bin/true
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/true...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/true.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4014c0: file true.c, line 59.
Starting program: /usr/bin/true 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde28) at true.c:59
59    if (argc == 2)
(gdb) p $instn_length($pc)
$1 = 3
(gdb) disassemble /r $pc, $pc + 4
Dump of assembler code from 0x4014c0 to 0x4014c4:
```

An alternative implementation of **instn_length()** is to use the **gdb.Architecture.disassemble()** method in GDB 7.6+:

```
def instn_length(addr_expr):
    addr = long(gdb.parse_and_eval(addr_expr))
    arch = gdb.selected_frame().architecture()
    return arch.disassemble(addr)[0]['length']
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to integrating Python with GDB so I wasn't sure if I could make it work in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a suitable solution; however, shorter solutions would be preferred. This solution sets a logging file to `/dev/null`, sets to to be overridden if it exists, and then redirects the console output to the log file temporarily.

```
define get-in-length
  set logging file /dev/null
  set logging overwrite on
  set logging redirect on
  set logging on
  x/2i $arg0
  set logging off
  set logging redirect off
  set logging overwrite off
  set $_in_length = ((unsigned long) $_) - ((unsigned long) $arg0)
end
```

This solution was heavily inspired by another question's answer: [How to get my program name in GDB when writting a "define" script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240596/how-to-get-my-program-name-in-gdb-when-writting-a-define-script).